# How to disable caching in OpenJPA 2.0.1 (edit: Issues with BoneCP)

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa, bonecp

I'm unable to disable caching in OpenJPA 2.0.1.

I have set the following properties in my *persistence.xml*:

```
<property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="false"/> <!-- I don't believe this is  necessary -->
```

And I can see that the correct values of these properties are logged out when I start my app.

I have created a basic entity to test this with, with a main method that simply queries the table every second. I'm creating a new EntityManager on each iteration. When I run this against an empty TEST table, and then subsequently manually insert data into test:

```
insert into TEST values (1,'a');
```

it never picks up on the new data (although if I re-start the program it does).

```
import java.util.List;    
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name="TEST")
public class Test {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // SIMPLE TEST CASE
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("su3", null);
        while(true) {
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            TypedQuery<Test> q = em.createQuery("select t from Test t", Test.class);
            List<Test> res = q.getResultList();
            for (Test t :res) {
                System.out.println(t.getId()+", " + t.getName());
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1**: If I create a new EntityManagerFactory **inside** the while loop, it works, but my understanding is that because I have set DataCache and QueryCache to false I do not need to do this, as well as it being expensive to do so.

**EDIT2**: I was using [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) as my connection pool manager, when I reverted to using DHCP or C3P0 the problem goes away. Not sure why though...

**EDIT3**: This is the config I was using for BoneCP:

```
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionProperties" value="DriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb,Username=xxxx,Password=yyyy,partitionCount=3"/>
```

Comment: Adding partitionCount=3 etc to your connection string doesn't make sense. That line is parsed by the driver, not the pool.

Comment: Have you come to solve this issue? I have run into the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by reverting back to the c3p0 driver, with the following config:

```
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName"  value="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionProperties" value="DriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname,characterEncoding=UTF8,useUnicode=true,user=username,password=password,autocommit=false,automaticTestTable=testtable,idleConnectionTestPeriod=60"/>
<property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
```